# Помогите переделать код создания частиц по нажатию на кнопку, в функцию создания частиц в любом месте через JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

взял с сайта эффект создания частиц по клику кнопки, собственно вот он

```js
function pop (e) {
    let amount = 30;
    switch (e.target.dataset.type) {
        case 'shadow':
        case 'line':
        amount = 60;
        break;
    }
    if (e.clientX === 0 && e.clientY === 0) {
        const bbox = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = bbox.left + bbox.width / 2;
        const y = bbox.top + bbox.height / 2;
        for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            createParticle(x, y, e.target.dataset.type);
        }
        } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            createParticle(e.clientX, e.clientY, e.target.dataset.type);
        }
    }
}
function createParticle (x, y, type) {
    const particle = document.createElement('particle');
    document.body.appendChild(particle);
    let width = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 8);
    let height = width;
    let destinationX = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000;
    let destinationY = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000;
    let rotation = Math.random() * 520;
    let delay = Math.random() * 200;
    switch (type) {
        
        
        
        case 'shadow':
        var color = `hsl(${Math.random() * 50 + 200}, 70%, 50%)`; // Цвет 
        particle.style.boxShadow = `0 0 ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 10)}px ${color}`; // Тень
        particle.style.background = color;
        particle.style.borderRadius = '50%'; // Радиус
        width = height = Math.random() * 100 + 4; // Размеры
        break;
        
    }
    particle.style.width = `${width}px`;
    particle.style.height = `${height}px`;
    const animation = particle.animate([
        {
            transform: `translate(-50%, -50%) translate(${x}px, ${y}px) rotate(0deg)`,
            opacity: 1
        },
        {
            transform: `translate(-50%, -50%) translate(${x + destinationX}px, ${y + destinationY}px) rotate(${rotation}deg)`,
            opacity: 0
        }
        ], {
        duration: Math.random() * 1000 + 5000, // Продолжительность всех эффектов
        easing: 'cubic-bezier(0, .9, .57, 1)',
        delay: delay
    });
    animation.onfinish = removeParticle;
}
function removeParticle (e) {
    e.srcElement.effect.target.remove();
}
if (document.body.animate) {
    document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', pop));
}
```

```css
particle {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
.div {
  background: rgb(98, 104, 252, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div clss="div">
  <button data-type="shadow">Кнопка</button>
</div>
```

Однако мне хочется использовать данный код создания частиц без кнопки. я пробовал сам пересобрать, у меня не получилось. Скажите пожалуйста как вызывать создание этих частиц в каком то месте через JS.

Comment: в идеале хотелось бы функцию в которую я бы мог просто передать координаты места спавна

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полагаю, это можно решить вот так:

```js
function pop(effectType, coordinateX, coordinateY, bounding = {
  'width': 60,
  'height': 21,
  'top': 250,
  'left': 250
}) {
  let amount = 30;
  switch (effectType) {
    case 'shadow':
    case 'line':
      amount = 60;
      break;
  }
  if (coordinateX === 0 && coordinateY === 0) {
    const bbox = bounding;
    const x = bbox.left + bbox.width / 2;
    const y = bbox.top + bbox.height / 2;
    for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      createParticle(x, y, effectType);
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
      createParticle(coordinateX, coordinateY, effectType);
    }
  }
}

function createParticle(x, y, type) {
  const particle = document.createElement('particle');
  document.body.appendChild(particle);
  let width = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 8);
  let height = width;
  let destinationX = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000;
  let destinationY = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000;
  let rotation = Math.random() * 520;
  let delay = Math.random() * 200;
  switch (type) {



    case 'shadow':
      var color = `hsl(${Math.random() * 50 + 200}, 70%, 50%)`; // Цвет 
      particle.style.boxShadow = `0 0 ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 10)}px ${color}`; // Тень
      particle.style.background = color;
      particle.style.borderRadius = '50%'; // Радиус
      width = height = Math.random() * 100 + 4; // Размеры
      break;

  }
  particle.style.width = `${width}px`;
  particle.style.height = `${height}px`;
  const animation = particle.animate([{
      transform: `translate(-50%, -50%) translate(${x}px, ${y}px) rotate(0deg)`,
      opacity: 1
    },
    {
      transform: `translate(-50%, -50%) translate(${x + destinationX}px, ${y + destinationY}px) rotate(${rotation}deg)`,
      opacity: 0
    }
  ], {
    duration: Math.random() * 1000 + 5000, // Продолжительность всех эффектов
    easing: 'cubic-bezier(0, .9, .57, 1)',
    delay: delay
  });
  animation.onfinish = removeParticle;
}

function removeParticle(e) {
  e.srcElement.effect.target.remove();
}
//if (document.body.animate) {
//document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', pop));
//}
pop('shadow', 250, 250); //Вызываем в любом месте с теми параметрами, какие нам необходимы
```

```css
particle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.div {
  background: rgb(98, 104, 252, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <button data-type="shadow">Кнопка</button>
</div>
```

P.S. С вашего позволения исправил опечатку в строке `<div class="div">`

Comment: честно сказать сам уже разобрался и сделал функцию которая n раз вызывает функцию createPrticle, но спасибо, хорошее решение